# How would I find the point 'Q' on the line that is closest to the line given?

Tags: vectors, parametric

Find the point $$Q$$ on the line

$$(-10,-6,-14) + s(-10,4,-2)$$

that is closest to the line

$$(49,28,-26) + t(-50,-38,22)$$

I'm not sure what information I need to use to complete this question. Here is one of my attempts:

I first used both matrices that are multiplied by $s$ and $t$ to make the equation $r= P+td$ which gives me

$$r= (-10,4,-2) + t(-50,-38,22).$$

$$r= (-10-50t, 4-38t, -2+22t)$$

After that, I try to find the equation of the distance while plugging in the first matrix point.

$$d= \sqrt{(-10-50t+10)^2 + (4-38t+6)^2 + (-2+22t+14)^2}$$

Unfortunately the answer I get if I do solve this above equation is quite messy and would not allow me to find the derivative which I assume is the next step.

Comment: The vector connecting $Q$ with the closest point $R$ on the other line must be perpendicular to both lines. This gives two linear equations with two unknowns $s,t$.

Comment: If you take cross product of the two vectors parallel to the given lines the result is perpendicular to both lines. Try find a point on each line so that the line segment connecting them is perpendicular to both lines.

Comment: If you wanted to minimise $d$, you could try minimising $d^2$ instead, as $d^2$ has a nicer derivative. That said, I don't really follow how you got $d$, or how minimising it would help you. I suspect that your method is unsound.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out your working. Here's my suggestion:

Let $P$ be the point on the second line that is closest to the first. Then we have $$\vec{OP}=(49,28,−26)+t(−50,−38,22)\\\vec{OQ}=(−10,−6,−14)+s(−10,4,−2)\\\vec{QP}=(59,34,−12)+t(−50,−38,22)-s(−10,4,−2).$$ Since $\vec{PQ}$ is perpendicular to each of the two lines, $$\vec{QP}\cdot(−10,4,−2)=0=\vec{QP}\cdot(−50,−38,22)\\\Big((59,34,−12)+t(−50,−38,22)-s(−10,4,−2)\Big)\cdot(−10,4,−2)\\=0=\\\Big((59,34,−12)+t(−50,−38,22)-s(−10,4,−2)\Big)\cdot(−50,−38,22).$$ Solving gives $$t=25625/27434,s=-66777/54868,$$ so $$Q=(2.17048188379,-10.8681927535,-11.5659036232).$$ Extra information: $$P=(2.29700371801,-7.49427717431,-5.45068163593)\\PQ=6.9853.$$